# Why does gdb need enter btn pressed twice for every command?

Tags: gdb

GDB has this bug, or maybe a feature I don't know of. I need to press enter twice for every command.

For example, if I type `step` then hit `enter`, on the second line the first character appears, when I hit `enter` again the command appears fully on the second line then the command gets executed.

[image]

Comment: i tried power shell, same bug happens.

Comment: Ok this appears to be a cmd specific with gdb only.
I tried gdb from msys2 command line and commands need only one enter press.

Comment: I have this problem too, hope someone could fix it.